# Graph to bipartite graph by removing edges (not more than edges/2) - algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, bipartite

so lets say we're given a graph and you're allowed to remove edges (not more than (original graph's edges)/2) until it's a bipartite graph.

Lets say we're given:

```
E={ (4, 1),( 1 ,2), (2 ,3),( 7, 2),( 1 ,5),( 8 ,4), (5 ,8),( 8, 9)}
```

and set of vertices:

```
V= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

How one should solve this problem ? Is there any kind of algorithm that does this? Any kind of explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick an arbitrary node as the first member of set A. If there is any node linked to it, pick one as the first member of set B. If not, pick any other node as the first member of set B.

Now you have two sets of nodes, A and B. Repeatedly pick a node not in either set. Count the number of edges linking that node to nodes in A and B. If there are more edges linking it to set A, erase the edges linking it to nodes in set B and put it in set B. Otherwise erase the edges linking it to nodes in set A and put it in set A. Note that you erase no more than half the edges linked to that node.

Comment: What if the amount of edges linking to set A and set B are equal ?

Comment: If the number of edges is the same either way it doesn't matter which choice you make, because you are still removing no more than half the edges under consideration.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Makes sense now. Is this solution well-known? - By that I mean is it a generic way of solving this problem? - Or is it your own implementation?

Comment: It wasn't well known to me - in fact I couldn't think of a problem I'd seen before that looked like this, so I just looked to see what taking it one step at a time would do.

Comment: `Now you have two sets of nodes, A and B` Has the entire graph been already been divided into 2 parts?

Comment: If you start with two nodes linked by a single edge you will change nothing and notice that you already have a bipartite graph. This is divided into to parts in the sense that it is a bipartite graph but not otherwise - it forms a single connected component.